# pause event is not working properly in PhoneGap iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

This is my code

```
    //This is an event that fires when a PhoneGap application is put into the background.
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

    //This is an event that fires when a PhoneGap application is retrieved from the background.
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

    // Handle the pause event
    function onPause(){
    console.log("pause : app is put into background");
    }


    // Handle the resume event
    function onResume() {
    console.log("resume : app is put into foreground");
    }
```

When i press the home button there is no log in the console however when I click the app (make it in foreground) then my log is

```
2011-11-22 12:11:37.206 Event[644:207] [INFO] pause : app is put into background
2011-11-22 12:11:37.206 Event[644:207] [INFO] resume : app is put into foreground
```

I don't know why pause function is called when it comes in foreground.
Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from the docs

[iOS Quirks](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#Events)

> In the pause handler, any calls that go through Objective-C will not work, nor will any calls that are interactive, like alerts. This means that you cannot call console.log (and its variants), or any calls from Plugins or the PhoneGap API. These will only be processed when the app resumes (processed on the next run-loop).

Comment: I am having same issue. I understand console.long wont work when i press home button to minimize application but when i resume it, there should be a message right?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working for me is there a way I can check what could be wrong? I also tried console.log on documentready but that didn't work either so maybe I am doing something wrong. I pasted my code here for you to see if you can spot the issue that would be really helpful. http://jsfiddle.net/6QXY7/

Comment: tried that doesn't seem to work. My code is same as the one in docs

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what is actually happening is that the console.log() from the pause event is not so much being fired on resume, as it's just that the system cannot output your console.log() until it comes back.

The Objective-C method in `PhoneGapDelegate.m` that fires the pause event (`applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application`) sends it to the JavaScript but by then the app is in the background and suspended. The JavaScript cannot receive the event until it re-enters the foreground.

To test this, simply background your app for a longer period of time... it should then cause their error:

`void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode`

This appears to be a bug in PhoneGap. Perhaps you could raise an issue at: https://github.com/callback/callback-ios ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.... I will check it and will try to get the exact answer.. and I'm not getting any error when app is in background for a long time... also where is this method `void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:)`

Comment: Perhaps that error was specific to my test application. I have added an issue at https://github.com/callback/callback-ios/issues/17 that might help. There are currently not events being fired for `applicationWillResignActive` or `applicationDidBecomeActive`. These might be better for stopping timers, etc when the app is not active.