# JQ Mobile, Phone Gap return to login screen when app is closed?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Ok so I have my first little app in JQ Mobile along with phonegap. Basically it just logs into a remote server if it authenticates it moves to an upload page.

What I would like to do when the app is closed is send the app back to the login page. This way they have to log in everytime they use the app.

Is there a function like on app close or something? Or is there a better solution to doing this?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the phone is closed, the `pause` event is fired.

To handle this event, you can do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

function onPause() {
    // Handle the pause event
}
```

[Here is a more complete example in the PhoneGap docs.](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#pause)

Comment: If you have problems with 'pause' (see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8224125/878602) then you could try to just reset it on 'resume' instead - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#resume