# Accessing localStorage when home button is pressed in Phonegap/iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

I need to store some values from my javascript code on the html5 local storage everytime the home button is pressed, before my app (Phonegap/iOS) exits. As I understand, the pause() and resume() phonegap events are not fired on iOS (iOS quirks). 
How can I store javascript values when the device home button is pressed?

Comment: Although I cant see an answer have you looked at the 'Resign' event ? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223020/pause-event-is-not-working-properly-in-phonegap-iphone

Comment: @AdamWare: Resing event works fine, for the Lock button. That is cool, but I need to get the same behavior for the home button instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store values in localStorage right at the time when you know them, and do not wait until user presses Home.

Comment: Yes, it is a good option and I am doing it so. Actually, I am using a setInterval function, so I am storing my values on each second. Thanks.